# loop through an array of objects does not stop on if statement

Tags: arrays, ajax, loops, foreach

This is my first question. I have a code in which I am trying to add an object to an array in local storage. If it already exists, I check it and want to stop the loop. However, this only happens on the first element which is created when the loop is empty. Could you please, look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong. I have tried:

- for loop
- some
- forEach

The arguments in the function are to fetch variables from other function, I'm using AJAX to fetch some data. I know that forEach doesn't accept return statement, that's why the code is commented out.

Thanks in advance
Code:

```
var counter = 0;

function bookmarkNewsSource(that, x, data, newsName) {

    myBookmark = {
        count: counter,
        imgNum: x,
        id: data.sources[x].id,
        name: data.sources[x].name
    };

    // check if fullTask already exists
    if (localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") === null) {
        //if not init array     
        var bookmarks = [];     
        //add to an array
        bookmarks.push(myBookmark);
        counter++;
        //set localstorage and convert object to a string
        localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    } else {
        var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));    
        // bookmarks.forEach((bookmark, index, array) => {
        //     console.log(bookmark, index);
        //     if (newsName == bookmark.name) {
        //         return 'done';
        //     } else {
        //         bookmarks.push(myBookmark);
        //         localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
        //         counter++;      
        //     }
        // });   

        bookmarks.some((bookmark) => {
            if (newsName == bookmark.name) {
                console.log('yes', newsName);
                return false;
            } else {
                 JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));  
                 bookmarks.push(myBookmark);
                 localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
                 counter++;      
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it almost right, just need to return `true` when you have *found a match and want the loop to stop*. It's better explained at [MDN Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) -

> `some()` executes the callback function once for each element present
>   in the array until it finds one where callback returns a *truthy value*.
>   If such an element is found, `some()` immediately returns true

```
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));
    var isPresent = bookmarks.some((bookmark) => {
        if (newsName == bookmark.name) {
            console.log('Match Found', newsName);
            return true; //Exit loop and stop going through further elements.
        }
    });

    if (!isPresent) {
             bookmarks.push(myBookmark);
             localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
             counter++;      
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed but it still does not work. The thing is it executes correctly only on the first element(object) in an array. It only adds it once. However when I try to add, more of them, it fails and continues to do so. I also checked the index, and it correctly iterates and logs code from if statement, but it still continues to else statement. Sth must be wrong somewere else I guess.

Comment: Ohh I see, after looking closely at your code, it seems the problem is due to `else` inside `some()`, I have updated to include that as well now.

Comment: Excellent, that worked!! I tried different ways, but I guess I wasn't that far off from the right answer. Just the matter of placing code in a right place:D Thanks!